# Liking a post comment as a page: do followers get notified?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

If I like a comment on a wall post when I am logged in as a page, will people who liked the page get notified in their news feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People who liked the page will not notified in their news feed.